# Benefits of Custom Designed Algorithms

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

In many languages, for me specifically, Java and C++, there is an massive standard library. Many classic problems in computer science, search, sorting, hashing etc etc... are implemented in this library. My question is, are there any benefits of say implementing one's own algorithm versus simply using the library's version? Are there any particular instances were this would be true?

I only ask because in school a huge deal of time is spent on say sorting, however in my actual code I have found no reason to utilize this knowledge when people have already implemented and optimized a sorting algorithm in both Java and C++.

EDIT: I discussed this at length with a professor I know and I posted his response, can anyone think of more to add to it?

Comment: The libraries usually don't come with non-comparison sorts, which to be fair aren't useful all that often, but when they are they're almost always a lot faster than whatever sort happens to be in the library.

Comment: This is akin to the common "why do I need math?"

Comment: It's very useful, in fact almost necessary, to see prior art before one can develop something new.  Imagine an architect who has never studied how iconic and significant buildings were designed...  Extending the analogy, one may take an off-the-shelf design for some purposes, and design something derivative or new for another purpose.  It's hard to generalize, but you can't do much *ab novo* without studying prior works.  What's more, many pursuits require developing things that others have yet to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing this at length with professor of Computer Science, here were his opinions:

**Reasons to Use Libraries**

**1.** You are writing code with a deadline.

- There is no sense in hampering your ability to complete a project in a quick and timely manner. That's why libraries are written after all, to save time and avoid "reinventing the wheel"

**2.** If you want to optimize your code fully.

- Chances are the team of incredibly talented people who wrote the algorithm in Java or C++'s or whoever's library did a far better job at optimizing their algorithm for that language in however long it took them than you can possibly do in an hour or two. Or four.

**3.** You've already done previously solved this problem.

- If you have already solved this problem and have a good complete understanding of how it is designed you don't need to labor over a complex solution as you don't stand to gain much benefit.

That being said, there are still many reasons to make your own solution.

**Reasons to Do It Yourself**

**1.** A fundamental understanding of problem solving techniques and algorithms are completely necessary once you reach a problem that is better optimized by a non-library solution.

- If you have a highly specified problem, such things often come up when working with networking or gaming or such. It becomes invaluable to be able to spot situations in which a specific algorithm will outperform the libraries version.

**2.** Having a very good understanding of algorithms and their design and use makes you much more valuable in the work place.

- Any halfway decent programmer can write a function to compare two objects and then toss them into a library function, however the one that is able to spot a situation and ultimately improve the programs functionality and speed is going to be looked upon well by management.

**3.** Having the concept of how to do something is often just as, if not more so, valuable than being able to do it.

- With an outstanding knowledge of Java's libraries and how to use them, chances are you can field any problem in java with reasonable success. However when you get hired to work in erlang you're going to have some rough times ahead. Where if you had known how and not merely what Java's libraries did, you could move those ideas to any language.

**4.** We as programmers are never truly satisfied with merely having something "work".

- Chances are that you have an itch to understand why things work. It was this curiosity that probably drove you to this area of study. Don't deny this curiosity! Encourage it and learn to your hearts content.

**5.** Finally, there is a huge feeling of success and accomplishment that comes with creating your own personal way of sorting or hashing etc.

- Just imagine how cool your friends will see you when you proclaim that you can find the shortest path between 2 vertices in `n log(n)` time! On a serious note, it is very rewarding to know that you are completely capable of understanding and choosing an optimum solution based on knowledge. Not what some library gives you.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, the stock library functions will be more performant than anything you'll custom code.

If you have a highly specific (as opposed to a generic) problem, you may find a performance gain by coding a specialized function, but as a developer you should make a conscious effort to not "reinvent the wheel."

Answer (score 1):

Sorting is a good example to consider. If you know nothing whatsoever about the data to be sorted, except how to compare elements, then the standard sort algorithms fare well. In this situation, in C++, the STL sort will do fine.

But sometimes you know more about your data. For example, if your data consists of uniformly distributed numbers, a radix sort can be much faster. But radix sort is 'invasive' in the sense that it needs to know more about your data than simply whether one number is bigger than another. That makes it harder to write a generic interface that can be shared by everyone. So STL lacks radix sort and for this case you can do better by writing your own code.

Answer (score 1):

In general, standard libraries contain very fast code for very general problems. If you have a specific problem, you can in many cases do better than the library. Of course, you may eventually come across a complex problem which is not solved by a library, in which case the knowledge you have gained from studying solutions to solved problems could prove invaluable.

Answer (score 1):

In college, or school, or if learning as a recreational programmer, you will be (or in my strident opinion, you should be) encouraged to implement a subset of these things yourself. Why? To learn. Tackling the implementation of an important already invented wheel (the B-Tree) for me was one of the most *formative* experiences of my time in college.

Sure I would agree that as a developer you should make an effort not to reinvent the wheel, but when *learning* through formative experiences, different rules apply. I read somewhere else on this forum that to use something at abstraction level N, it is a very good idea to have a working knowledge of abstraction level N-1, and be familiar with level N-2. I would agree. In addition to being formative, it prepares you for the day when you *do* encounter a problem when the stock libraries are not a good fit. Believe me this can happen in your 50 year career. If you are learning fundamentals such as `data structures`, where the end goal is not the completeness of your finished product but, instead, self improvement, it is time well spent to "re-invent the wheel".

Answer (score 1):

Is pre-algebra/algebra/trigonometry/calculus worth learning?

I can't tell if this is a "am I wasting my time/money in school" aimed question or if this is a sincere question of if your own version is going to be better.

As for wasting your time/money in school: If all you want to do is take pot shots at developing a useful application, then you're absolutely wasting your time by learning about these already-implemented algorithms -- you just need to kludge something together that works good 'nuff.

On the other hand if you're trying to make something that really matters, needs to be fast, and needs to be the right tool for the right job -- well, then it often doesn't exist already and you'll be back at some site like Stack Overflow asking first or second year computer science questions because you're not familiar enough with existing techniques to roll your own variations.

Depending on my job, I've been on both sides. Do I need to develop it fast, or does it have to work well? For fast application programming, it's stock functions galore unless there's a performance or functionality hindrance I absolutely must resolve. For professional game programming it has to run blazing fast. That's when the real knowledge kicks into memory management, IO access optimization, computational geometry, low level and algorithmic optimization, and all sorts of clever fun. And it's rarely ever a stock implementation that gets the job done.

And did I learn most of that in school? No, because already knew most of it, but the degrees helped without a doubt. On the other hand you *don't* know most of it (otherwise you wouldn't be asking), so yes, in short: **It is worthwhile.**

Some specific examples:

- If you ever want to make truly amazing games, live and breath algorithms so you can code what other people can't. If you want to make fun games that aren't particularly amazing, use stock code and focus on design. It's limiting, but it's faster development.
- If you want to program embedded devices (a rather large market), often stock code just won't do. Often there's a code or data memory constraint that the library implementations won't satisfy.
- If you need serious server performance from modest hardware, stock code won't do. [(See this Slashdot entry.)](http://it.slashdot.org/story/12/02/21/2115237/how-mailinator-compresses-its-email-stream-by-90)
- If you ever want to do any interesting phone development the resource crunch requires you to get clever, even often for "boring" applications. (User experience is everything, and the stock sort function on a large section of data is often just too slow.)
- Often the libraries you're restricted to using don't do what you need. (For example, C# doesn't have a "stable" sort method. I run into this annoyance all the time and have since written my own solution.)
- If you're dealing with large amounts of data (most businesses have it these days) you'll end up running into situations where an interface is too slow and needs some clever workarounds, often involving good use of custom data structures.

Answer (score 1):

Those libraries offer you tested implementations that work well, so the rule of thumb is to use those implementations. If you have a very particular/complex problem where you can use some domain knowledge you have a case were you will need to implement your own version of an algorithm.

I remember an example Bill Pugh gave in his programming languages class where they analyzed the performance of a complex application and they realized a faulty custom implementation of a sorting algorithm by a programmer (that code was used many times in the real runs of the application) was responsible for 90% performance decrease!